# How to overwrite commerce product details tpl.twig (commerce-product.html.twig) in theme template in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I created a bunch of products, but I need to style them per the designer's design. I know that I have to overwrite the template from /modules/contrib/commerce/modules/product/templates/commerce-product.html.twig but where do I put it in my theme?

Does it go to the root of my templates folder? What is the correct way to style the single product page?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates:

> 1. Locate the template you wish to override.
> 2. Copy the template file from its base location into your theme folder.
> 3. (optionally) Rename the template according to the naming conventions in order to target a more specific subset of areas where the template is used.
> 4. Modify the template to your liking.

You may have to clear the caches to have Drupal recognize the new file.

So usually you have a `templates` folder in your theme, there you can drop all custom twig files.